# Linear Regression Expected Value

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, linear

Whiles reading **An Introduction To Statistical Learning** under linear regression (Chapter 3), I found:

$$E(Y - \hat{Y})^2 = |f(X) - \hat{f}(X)|^2 + Var(ε)$$

where $E(Y - \hat{Y})^2$ represents the average, or expected value of the squared difference between the predicted and actual value of $Y$, and $Var(ε)$ represents the *variance* associated with the error term $ε$.

What does $Var(ε)$ mean? Can we just write $ε$ rather than $Var(ε)$?

Comment: can you share the author and the page? and edition if applicable.

Comment: @Gunes see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=An+Introduction+To+Statistical+Learning.

Comment: Now I found it, thanks. It's in Page 19, not in Chapter 3. I was interested in finding some evidence about $X$ being fixed; and it is there. However, it appears the question is duplicate.